# Problems checking .net signature in java

Tags: c#, java, digital-signature

I'm signing xml document with x509Certificate in .net. If I verify signature in .net with signedXml.CheckSignature function the signature is ok. If I try to check the same signature in java i always get **java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrong Signature: Wrong Signature**. Anyone has experience with that?

```
public static bool verifyXMLSignature(XmlDocument ADoc, string ACertificateSerial)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        cert = podpisi.getCertificate(ACertificateSerial);



        // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
        // the XML document class.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(ADoc);

        // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
        // XmlNodeList object.
        XmlNodeList nodeList = ADoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

        // Load the signature node.
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        // Check the signature and return the result.
        return signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is the working c# code - the non-working code is the Java code which has not been posted. 
Knowing your Java code would allow us to point out where your problem may be located in the code...